# music play on load page in javascript

Tags: javascript, onload-event

I have the following code in javascript that plays a sound

```
function muzplay() {
   var muz = document.getElementById("song");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");

   if (muz.paused) {
      muz.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
   } else {
      muz.pause();
      button.textContent = ">";
   }
}
```

but it doesn't starts when the page is loading for the first time.
How can I make the song start when the page is loading?

If I would like to add an image as a button, instead of "button.textContent = "||";" what command can I use. for example I want to use a customize play and pause button instead of the || and > text.

Comment: How is the function called

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){ muzplay();}
// or
window.document.onload = function(){ muzplay();}
// or
muzplay();
```

Comment: If I would like to add an image as a button, instead of "button.textContent = "||";" what command can I use. for example I want to use a customize play and pause button instead of the || and > text.